# Call next function on .ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I must call another function on jQuery.ajax:success.

I tried:

```
function getJoinLeaveBtn(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl+"?action=get_group_ids&bp_ajax=get_button",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            getMembers(id);
        },
        error: function(req, status, error){
            showMessage(3,req.statusText);
        }
        , timeout: 20000
    });
}
```

But "getMembers" is never called on success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you're missing a comma `,` after the `url`

Comment: you're right, but I simplified the code for SO and missed it :) thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Prolly something you are doing that is not included in this sample code.